# Sphero API - Access while charging in cradle?

Tags: sphero-api

Is there any way to access the sphero while it is charging in its cradle? I'm looking to pass information to it but still have it cradled and charging (ie, change colors throughout the day without draining the battery). Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Yes. If it goes to sleep in the charger, you can't communicate with it at all, but you can set it to stay awake in the charger, which will allow you to still communicate with it. If you're developing toward Android, use the `SetOptionFlagsCommand` with a value of 1 to prevent it from sleeping. Use a value of 0 to allow it again.

Comment: Warning: might have a negative impact on your battery life.